# Creat react app Typescript jest is not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-typescript

I am tried to run the unit testing in my creat react app typescript. when i tried to run the unit testing i am getting error in my Interceptor. my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "react-typescript",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "homepage": "/login",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "^21.2.9",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-data": "^21.2.9",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-maps": "^22.1.34",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons": "^21.2.6",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts": "^22.1.34",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "^21.2.10",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids": "^21.2.9",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-inputs": "^21.2.9",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-layouts": "^22.1.34",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-maps": "^22.1.34",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-navigations": "^21.2.9",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-notifications": "^21.2.3",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "^22.1.38",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.12",
        "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.29.12",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.34",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "browserify-aes": "^1.2.0",
        "debug-es": "2.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.1.3",
        "i18next": "^22.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "node-rsa": "^1.1.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-i18next": "^12.3.1",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-app-rewired start",
        "build": "react-app-rewired build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.11",
        "@babel/register": "^7.22.5",
        "@rtk-query/codegen-openapi": "^1.0.0",
        "@types/i18next": "^13.0.0",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
        "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "url": "^0.11.1"
    }
}
```

.babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ]
}
```

jest.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
        "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
        "!<rootDir>/path/to/dir/"
    ]
};
```

i am getting error in Interceptor file is

[image]

how to fix this issue.

Note : When i google it the issue sayes
The error you're facing is due to the usage of ES6 module syntax (import/export) within your interceptor file, which is not directly supported in Node.js/CommonJS environment without proper transpilation. However, you're not supposed to transpile your application code manually, as Create React App (CRA) abstracts this process for you. The issue may stem from running the test directly without leveraging CRA's test runner.

my Interceptor code

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { has } from 'lodash';
import { store } from 'store';
import { getDataFromLocalStorage, setDataInLocalStorage } from 'utils/localstorage.utils';
import { messageDilogReducer } from 'reducers/message.reducer';
import { loaderReducer } from 'reducers/loader.reducer';
import { sessionDilogReducer } from 'reducers/sessiondilog.reducer';

// getting the base url from the .env file 
const { REACT_APP_BASE_URL } = process.env;

const apiServices = axios.create({
    baseURL: REACT_APP_BASE_URL, // Replace with your API URL
});

// Request interceptor
apiServices.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // Modify config if needed (e.g., add headers)
    return config;
}, (error) => {
    // Handle request error
    // console.log('req error', error)
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
);

const errorResonseFun = (error: AxiosError<unknown, any>) => {
    const { status } = error.response as AxiosResponse<unknown, any>;
    // The server responded with a status code outside the range of 2xx
    if (status === 401) {
        const {message } = error;
        store.dispatch(loaderReducer(false));
        console.log(error)
        store.dispatch(sessionDilogReducer({ display: 'inline-block', visible: true, message }));
    }
}

const errorRequestFun = (error: AxiosError<unknown, any>) => {
    const { message } = error;
    store.dispatch(loaderReducer(false));
    store.dispatch(messageDilogReducer({ message: message, type: 'error' }));
}

const errorDefaultFun = (error: AxiosError<unknown, any>) => {
    const { message } = error;
    store.dispatch(messageDilogReducer({ message: message, type: 'error' }));
    // window.location.href = '/';
}

// Response interceptor
apiServices.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        // Process successful responses
        const { headers } = response;
        const hasKey = has(headers, 'www-authenticate');
        if (hasKey) {
            const auth = getDataFromLocalStorage('auth');
            if (auth['www-authenticate'] !== headers['www-authenticate']) {
                setDataInLocalStorage('auth', headers);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }, (error: AxiosError<unknown, any>) => {
        // Handle response error
        const hasResponse = has(error, 'response');
        const hasRequest =  has(error, 'request');
        switch (true) {
            case hasResponse:
                errorResonseFun(error);
                break;
            case hasRequest:
                errorRequestFun(error);
                break;
            default:
                errorDefaultFun(error);
                break;
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);


export default apiServices;
```

my basic test case should run successfull

Comment: `import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Login from ".";

test('Login component test', () => {
    render(<Login />);
    const textElement = screen.getByText('Sign In');
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});`

Answer (score 1):

This error is being thrown because Jest is trying to parse code in your node_modules folder. In your `package.json` or jest config file add a jest section with the following `transformIgnorePatterns` rule:

```
...
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": "node_modules/(?!axios)"
}
```

Comment: @CII199 issue remain the same

Comment: @CII1999 i had updated the jest config `"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/(?!axios)"
    ]
}` its working fine